# ¿Cómo agregar Crystal Report en Visual Studio 2015 prof?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

estoy intentando instalar el módulo de `Crystal Report` en `Visual Studio 2015` y no consigo ver el editor de reports.

Me explico:

He descargado de la web de [sap](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads) el support pack18 64bits, mi S.O. WIN 7 profesional 64bits.

El caso es que una vez instalado no soy capaz de entender qué referencias tengo que agregar para poder tener el diseñador de reports en mi entorno de visual studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer estaba haciendo la instalación a medias, he leido un [ticket de stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531668/how-to-integrate-sap-crystal-reports-in-visual-studio-2015-enterprise-edition) y en la respuesta de @Orlando Herrera lo explica claramente:

1. Descargar el instalador.
2. Descargar y ejecutar el runtime de 32 o 64 bits.
   Una vez realizados estos pasos, al iniciar visual studio 2015 se pondrá a actualizar algunos componentes, pero ya al añadir un elemento nuevo en reporting aparece el Crystal Report, cosa que hasta ahora no había conseguido.